# What allows a function to remain equivalent to itself if a rewritten form of yields undefined results at a specific point(s)?

Tags: calculus, functions, factoring

Example:

$f(x) = \frac{x^2+2x-15}{x-3}$

Can be factored and rewritten as:

$f(x) = (x+5)$

At $x = 3$, the top, unaltered function yields *undefined*, while the bottom yields *8*.

If I am correct in my understanding, a factored version of an expression is essentially a rewritten but still equivalent form of the original expression. No matter the form of the expression or equation, I was under the impression that all forms of the same expression would maintain equivalency.
Is it that functions can sometimes have different outcomes but still maintain equivalency as long as the only difference is in an undefined value or values?

Is there a strict definition on "equivalency"? and is there a rule or law or anything concerning this?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The first thing is to notice is that, when you rewrite the first expression as the second expression, you have to assume that $x\neq -3$, otherwise it doesn't work. So you add information there. Therefore, when you say that $f(x) = x+5$, it's kinda incomplete. It should instead be
$$
f(x) = x+5 \qquad \text{with} \qquad x \neq -3
$$

Comment: One thing to remember is that a requirement for two functions to be equal is that they have equal domains. Since you don't specify them here, we typically assume the natural domain (the largest subset of the real numbers for which the function is defined). But the natural domain of the first function is $x \neq 3$ while the natural domain of the second is all real numbers. So for them to be equal you should write it as @MattiP. suggests above.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is!

As functions, they have different expressions and exist at different points, so they are NOT equivalent of course.

However, it is true that:
$$\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{x^2+2x-15}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to c}x+5$$
(for any $c$)

So since the limits hold up on both sides, you'd could remove the discontinuity of the first expression by replacing it by the second.

However, Matti P.'s comment is also correct - you need to explicitly state that the function does not exist at $x=-3$, because it doesn't without changing it. The act of "removing the discontinuity" is itself changing the function.